# Joining two tables with PreparedStatement

Tags: sql, jsf, jakarta-ee, prepared-statement

I have two tables; PLOT and ACCOMODATION. I want to select from both tables, join them together and then display them on the JSF page. However I'm new to SQL and JSF and I'm having trouble with the syntax for the SQL query.

### Tables

```
PLOT
PLOTNO, SITENO(foreign), ACCOMNO(foreign), STARTDATE, ENDDATE

ACCOMODATION
ACCOMNO(primary), ACCOMTYPE, SLEEPINGCAPACITY, TOILETFACILITY, PRICE
```

The desired result would be:

```
PLOTNO, ACCOMTYPE, SLEEPINGCAPACITY, TOILETFACILITY, PRICE, STARTDATE, ENDDATE
```

where the results are ordered by the `PLOTNO`

The code below shows my most recent attempt throwing this error: 
"Syntax error: Encountered "p" at line 1, column 135." I've tried many variations but all seem to throw a syntax error of some sort.

### Bean:

```
try {
        // create a PreparedStatement to get plot details
        PreparedStatement getPlotDetails = connection.prepareStatement
            ("SELECT "
                    + "p.PLOTNO, "
                    + "a.ACCOMTYPE, "
                    + "a.SLEEPINGCAPACITY, "
                    + "a.TOILETFACILITY, "
                    + "a.PRICE, "
                    + "p.STARTDATE, "
                    + "p.ENDDATE "
                    + "FROM PLOT p "

                    //+ "WHERE SITENO = 2; "

                    + "JOIN ACCOMODATION a"
                    + "ON p.ACCOMNO = a.ACCOMNO "

                    + "ORDER BY p.PLOTNO "
                    );
        CachedRowSet rowSet = new com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl();
        rowSet.populate(getPlotDetails.executeQuery());
        return rowSet; 
    } // end try
```

### JSF page:

```
<ui:define name="content">
        <h:dataTable value="#{dealsBean.plotDetailsLiverpool}" var="item"
                     rowClasses="oddRows, evenRows" headerClass="header"
                     styleClass="table" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Plot</f:facet>
                    #{item.PLOTNO}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Accom No.</f:facet>
                    #{item.ACCOMNO}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Accom Type</f:facet>
                    #{item.ACCOMTYPE}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Sleeps</f:facet>
                    #{item.SLEEPINGCAPACITY}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Toilet Facility?</f:facet>
                    #{item.TOILETFACILITY}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Price</f:facet>
                    #{item.PRICE}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Start Date</f:facet>
                    #{item.STARTDATE}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">End Date</f:facet>
                    #{item.ENDDATE}
            </h:column>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
+ "JOIN ACCOMODATION a"
+ "ON p.ACCOMNO = a.ACCOMNO "
```

there is no space between "....ACCOMODATION a" and "ON p.AC....."

replace them with something like this:

```
+ "JOIN ACCOMODATION a  "
+ "ON p.ACCOMNO = a.ACCOMNO "
```